# How to make a Java server HTTPS-ready?

Tags: java, https

I have a server written (*self written - no Tomcat or Jetty*) in Java and it works nicely, but now I want it to work with HTTPS as well, but I really don't get what I need to do. I've read some stuff online, but haven't really found a good explanation for what I need to do.

Could anybody give me an useful hint (or a small outline) of what needs to be done so HTTPS works?

Comment: Please attempt to use proper English for questions... This is a server you have written for scratch or source for a server you got somewhere else?

Comment: Is the server software a common server? If so then there could be directions online as part of documentation.

Comment: from scratch ... I think would be proper English ... and besides the fact, that I did not directly make clear, that it is a self written server, I do believe my English aint that bad ...

Comment: -1 For the rant (which luckily someone removed already from the question, but there's still more in doro's comment above).

Comment: well, why is everyone else allowed to criticize me, but I am not allowed? sorry ... instead of criticizing, dun you think it might be more helpful to just help one another? why is it important whether i write "hey everyone" or not ... or make some stupid grammatical or orthographic error? i was looking for help, not ppl putting me down ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to give a short answer to my own question:

*the sslcontext has to be configured correctly ...*

Answer (score 3):

You can use an http to https [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), or an SSL proxy like [stunnel](http://stunnel.mirt.net/), in front of your java server. That way you do not have to modify it.

```
 Browser ---(HTTPS)---> Proxy ---(HTTP)---> YourServer
```

The proxy can run an the same system as the web server, will handle the encryption stuff, and connect locally to the webserver. That way you offer both HTTP and HTTPS on the same host.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a good starting point:
[Secure Internet Programming](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/secureinternet/) [java.sun.com]

I'll try to cater the answer better to your needs once you supply more information.

Comment: Thnx, that might be a link that could help very much. I'll look through it.

Answer (score 0):

What server are you using for your application?  Tomcat, Jetty, and others each have different methods for configuring SSL support.

Comment: Hey, sorry, that I didn't make it clear: we wrote it ourselves ... It's not a server you can find anywhere. We used the Java-classes for that.